# Jquery button back to original state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which if i click rotates to 25deg, I achieved this using Jquery. But now I want that if i click it again that it goes to its original state. This is what I got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        $('.fa-plus-circle').click(function() {

            $(this).prev('p').slideToggle();

            $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(20deg)');

            $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(-20deg)');

            return false;



        });
    });

});
```

As you can see i tried adding:

```
 $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(-20deg)');
```

right after the first rotation.

Comment: Why don't you use a (boolean) flag and execute different code based on that flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flag to determine whether it is rotated or not. Here is an example:

```js
var rotated = false;
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).css('transform', rotated ? 'rotate(0deg)' : 'rotate(20deg)');
  rotated = !rotated;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(function() {
    $('.fa-plus-circle').click(function() {

      $(this).toggleClass('rotated');

      return false;



    });
  });

});
```

```css
.fa-plus-circle {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.fa-plus-circle.rotated {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fa-plus-circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this:

$(function() {
  $('.fa-plus-circle').click(function() {

    var el = $(this);

    el.prev('p').slideToggle();

    if(el.hasClass('active')) {
      el.css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
    } else {
      el.css('transform', 'rotate(20deg)');
    }

    el.toggleClass('active');

    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="fa-plus-circle">
    Hello
</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var rotated = false;  
    $('.fa-plus-circle').click(function() {
    if(rotated === false) {
      $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(20deg)');
      rotated = true;
    } else {
        $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
        rotated = false;
    }

    return false;
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle e.g.](https://jsfiddle.net/yzuowrzr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following simple approach to check if an element has been transformed:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('.fa-plus-circle').click(function() {
            $(this).prev('p').slideToggle();
            var transformed = $(this).css('transform') !== "none";
            $(this).css('transform', (transformed)? 'none': 'rotate(-20deg)');

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="fa-plus-circle">hello</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ppgbsb0/